# Join 2 non existing tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having trouble joining two tables that come from two queries, meaning I don't have the actual table in my database. I have the following:

```
SELECT
    fiscalYear,
    BidOwner,
    count(cbid) AS c
FROM
    financials_tbl
GROUP BY
    BidOwner,
    fiscalYear
```

that one brings each BidOwner for each year with the amounts of bids he/she did that year.

Now this one:

```
SELECT
    fiscalYear,
    max(c)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            fiscalYear,
            BidOwner,
            count(cbid) AS c
        FROM
            financials_tbl
        GROUP BY
            BidOwner,
            fiscalYear
    ) InputTable
GROUP BY
    fiscalYear
```

brings the maximum amount of bids done by an employee that year (2 columns).

What I need is to join this last table with the corresponding bid owner from the previous one, like a vlookup to find who scored the max amount of deals each year shown in the second table.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: so the first querie would be like 2012 John Smith 45, 2013 John Smith 52, 2014 John Smith 34, 2012 Jane Doe 40, 2013 Jane Doe 57....the second querie would bring 2012 45, 2013 57...... so what i need is to join the tables so that i could have something like 2012 45 John Smith, 2013 57 Jane Doe.....This is for MYSQL

Comment: I can only you refer to the comment I made previously.

Comment: If you had the two results from these two queries in Excel and you had to combine them by hand, how would you do that? You say for that second SQL statement "brings the maximum amount of bids done by an employee that year (2 columns)." but it doesn't do that. There is no employee in the output, so there is no way to determine which employee is the `max` here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to find a groupwise maximum on the result of your count query. Unfortunately, I do not know a way to do this without creating two of the same subquery, but I think this should work.

```
SELECT
    t1.fiscalYear, t1.BidOwner, t1.c
FROM
    (SELECT fiscalYear, BidOwner, count(cbid) AS c
     FROM financials_tbl
     GROUP BY BidOwner, fiscalYear) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT fiscalYear, BidOwner, count(cbid) AS c
     FROM financials_tbl
     GROUP BY BidOwner, fiscalYear) t2
ON t1.fiscalYear = t2.fiscalYear AND t1.c < t2.c
WHERE t2.BidOwner IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the results in such way:

```
SELECT
t2.fiscalYear,
t2.BidOwner,
t2.c
FROM (
    SELECT
        fiscalYear,
        max(c) as max
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                fiscalYear,
                BidOwner,
                count(cbid) AS c
            FROM
                financials_tbl
            GROUP BY
                BidOwner,
                fiscalYear
        ) InputTable
    GROUP BY
        fiscalYear
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        fiscalYear,
        BidOwner,
        count(cbid) AS c
    FROM
        financials_tbl
    GROUP BY
        BidOwner,
        fiscalYear  
) t2
ON  t2.max = t1.c
AND t2.fiscalYear = t1.fiscalYear;
```

However performance of such query will not be nice for large data sets...